# how to make the layout in tailwind still be mobile even on the desktop

Tags: html, css, reactjs, layout, tailwind-css

how to make the layout in tailwind still be mobile even on the desktop

```html
<div className='bg-sky-600'>

      <div className="max-w-4xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="max-w-2xl mx-auto">
        <MainNavbar/>
        <div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Something like this > https://play.tailwindcss.com/O5es5mwQ5W?size=894x803 ?